# image-less pure-CSS arrow tags

Tags: css

Is there a way a way to create Delicious-like "arrow tags" without the use of images:
[image: Delicious tags]

I'm familiar with the [border-triangle technique](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/), but couldn't get that to look decent (in part because we'd need an additional outer border to frame the entire component).

Comment: If I remember correctly, SVG doesn't just work out of the box across all browsers - plus with HTML + CSS, you (hopefully) get much more graceful degradation.

Comment: The browsers that don't support SVG generally won't support CSS3.

Comment: Indeed - thus my comment regarding graceful degradation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I create a little example may be that's you want .

**CSS**

```
div{
    padding:5px 10px;
    font-size:12px;
    -moz-border-radius:0 5px 5px 0;
    -webkit-border-radius:0 5px 5px 0;
    float:left;
    margin-left:30px;
    margin-top:20px;
    position:relative;
    font-family:verdana;
    color:#3b3d3c;
    border:1px solid #d5d5d7;
    border-left:0;
}

div{
    background: -moz-linear-gradient( top , #fbfdfc 0%,#f6f5f5 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient( top , #fbfdfc 0%,#f6f5f5 100%);  
}

div:after{
    content:"";
     width:18px;
     height:18px;
     background: -moz-linear-gradient( left top , #fbfdfc 0%,#f6f5f5 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient( left top , #fbfdfc 0%,#f6f5f5 100%);
     -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
     -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
     display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:3px;
    left:-10px;
    z-index:-1;
    border:1px solid  #d5d5d7;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/9EEEP/76/

**UPDATED**
Now work in chrome also

http://jsfiddle.net/9EEEP/77/

For more you check my this answer also [How to code certain css shapes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009587/how-to-code-certain-css-shapes/8009869#8009869)

I use css3 which not work in IE8 below browsers.

Comment: Please post your code here, not just at JS Fiddle, for future reference. And to cover the likelihood of JS Fiddle falling over.

Comment: This has a weird tag at the bottom of the triangle on chrome.

Comment: just out of curiosity, I wonder if, performance-speaking, is it better to use image instead of CSS? I mean those lines of CSS could take some roughly 1-2 KB in size.

Comment: In this CSS is better because if see the image you have to cut 4 to 5 image & make theme flexible according to the text. Which much heavy then css.

Comment: Thanks, this is very nice! However, it currently seems a little buggy in Firefox; the arrow tip and shaft don't have exactly the same height (try zooming). I'll play around with it a bit before accepting; perhaps using non-pixel units will help.

Comment: adding `line-height: 1.4em;` made it look alright in Firefox, though it still doesn't survive zooming - unfortunately, I couldn't get it to work using `em` instead of `px`.

Comment: Interesting, but that CSS is incredibly fragile. I found it almost impossible to adapt outside of that simple JSFiddle example. The slightest alteration causes the arrow to disappear.